# Computing ECDF of a data for parameter estimation using weighted nonlinear least square in R

Tags: r, nls

I am writing a code for estimating the parameter of a GPD using weighted nonlinear least square(WNLS) method.
The WNLS method consist of 2 steps

step 1: $(\hat{\xi_1} , \hat{b_1}) = arg\ \min_{(\xi,b)} \sum_{i=1}^{n} [\log(1-F_n(x_i)) - log(1-G_{\xi,b}(x_i))]$,
here $F_n$ is the ECDF and $1-G_{\xi,b}$ is the generalized pareto distribution.

Can anyone let me know how to calculate EDF function $F_n$ for a data "X" in R?
Does `ecdf(X)(X)` will calculate the ECDF? If so then, what is the need for `ecdf(X)` other than plotting? Also it would be really helpful if someone share some example code which involves the calculation of ECDF for data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ecdf` call creates a function. That is, you can apply `ecdf(X)` to other data, as your `ecdf(X)(X)` call does. However, you might want to apply `ecdf(X)` to something other than `X` itself. If you want to know the empirical quantile to which two numbers `a`, and `b` correspond, an easy way to do that is to call `ecdf(X)(c(a, b))`.